# Question about what shows up in my git log

Tags: git

I had a branch in git that got a little too off track, so I decided to made a new branch from the current master and instead cherry-pick the commits one-by-one to have more control over how it developed. I thought the best way to do this would be to use

```
git log current_master..off_track_branch --reverse
```

to get the list of commits, and then use those hashes to cherry-pick to my liking. I would have expected that once I did cherry-pick a commit it wouldn't anymore show up in my git log (since that commit was no longer a difference between them).

Much to my surprise no matter how many commits I cherry picked the log looks the same. Why is this so, and is there a way to adjust the settings so that I only see the commits I haven't cherry picked yet?

Comment: Are you cherry-picking them onto master or a new branch?

Comment: cherry-picking onto the new branch

Comment: It would appear in logs just not diff. Am I getting your question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are cherry-picking onto a new branch so master isn't changing. Try doing a log between your two branches.

`git log new_branch..off_track_branch --reverse`

Answer (score 0):

When you cherry-pick, you are creating new revisions that are **in now way related** to the revisions that you are cherry-cherry-picking so if you run a log between the two branches you will see all those revisions, the new ones and the old ones as well.